# How can I get the Stalker to spawn?

Tags: warframe

On Warframe, what triggers to ability to have a Stalker to spawn stalking you. Do you have to get the killing blow against a boss? Or just be in the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Stalker](http://warframe.wikia.com/wiki/Stalker) spawning is completely random, it can happen to *almost* anyone at any time.
The reason I say 'almost everyone' is because you need to have killed at least one boss *since the last time you were Stalked* before the stalker can enter one of your games.

The first time I saw the stalker I was playing by myself, and I was relatively new to the game.  I doubt I had any last hits on any bosses at that time, though I had beaten some by playing online with others who did the killing for me.

So other than the initial condition of having to beat at least one boss in your entire career, the stalker can spawn at any time, in any game mode, on any player.

Comment: Note that only one of the people playing has to meet the requirements for being Stalked in order for Stalker to have a chance at showing up.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning, that you will get a message from the stalker after killing a boss. This message is the so-called "Death Mark".

Answer (score 0):

The stalker spawning is random, but it cannot spawn on an assassination mission. Also, keep in mind that enemies will attack the stalker and when he is down to 10% hp he will flee the game, but it will count as a kill.